# Slider fullscreen dentro de colunas bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3, slider

Boa tarde a todos.

Eu estou usando o bootstrap 3 e estou enfrentando um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver há mais de 1 semana.
Eu tenho um layout que tem 1 coluna para menu e outras 11 para ser um slider fullscreen.
Já tentei usar várias técnicas mas nada de funcionar. Alguém tem como me ajudar?

Eu estava tentando com este, mas também utilizei outros sem muito sucesso
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

Segue o link do exemplo do layout e do código simples.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFLla.jpg --> layout de exemplo

http://www.bootply.com/gQxMfEW4de --> código de exemplo que estava usando

Muito obrigado a todos.